# bitnami mongodb: get access replicaset behind traefik

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, traefik, bitnami, traefik-ingress

I've deployed my bitnami/mongodb helm chart:

```
helm install mongodb bitnami/mongodb \
  --set architecture="replicaset" \
  --set auth.enabled=false
```

Services:

```
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
mongodb-arbiter-headless   ClusterIP   None         <none>        27017/TCP   30m
mongodb-headless           ClusterIP   None         <none>        27017/TCP   30m
```

Both nodes are accesible behing `mongodb-headless`:

```yaml
Name:              mongodb-headless
Namespace:         salut
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
                   helm.sh/chart=mongodb-10.30.11
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: mongodb
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: salut
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb,app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                None
IPs:               None
Port:              mongodb  27017/TCP
TargetPort:        mongodb/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.9:27017,10.42.2.5:27017   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I've created this Traefik `IngressRoute` in order to get access to my deployed replicaset mongo:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - web
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`mongodb.localhost`)
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: mongodb-headless
      port: 27017
```

I need to get access from my host to this deployed replicaset, but I'm not able to reach it:

```
mongo mongodb://mongodb.localhost:80/mpi
MongoDB shell version v5.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://mongodb.localhost:80/mpi?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
...
...
...
...
waiting, bit never reached
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you provision your cluster? Have you tried setting your entry point to other port? Have you considered connecting to your mongoDB Pods using temporary client Pods?

Answer (score 2):

`IngressRoute` is for HTTP services. MongoDB is a TCP service so you should use [`IngressRouteTCP`](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroutetcp) instead.